# The median of infinity

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Would it be logical to assume that 1 is the median of countable infinity since all the whole numbers can also be used as its' denominator?

Comment: Any finite number has equal claim.  The explanation of why is squarely within the domain of mathematics, not philosophy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not philosophy.

Comment: That said, I do not think that math.SE will want this question either.

Answer (score 1):

What do denominators have to do with medians? Your question is confusing to me. However, I'll just talk about medians.

The median of a (finite, ordered) set is the value with an equal number of elements of the set above and below it.

If you want to extend the notion of median to infinite sets using the same definition, that's ok ... but you have to be careful. Here are two examples.

You can say that *any* member of the countable set of integers is the median. That's because there are always countably many numbers less, and countably many numbers greater, than any value.

So if you say that the median of the ordered set ..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... is zero, you're right. And if you say the median is 47, or -119, you're still right! *Every* number is the median, by the definition of median.

But if you take the ordered set of natural numbers, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... then NO number is the median. Because if you take any number like 47, only finitely many numbers are smaller than it and infinitely many are greater. So no number is the median.

You see that the notion of median depends critically on the particular *order* that you put on your set.

Countability doesn't have much to do with this, the same discussion goes through for uncountable sets. And remember, there are lots of different ways to order sets of a given cardinality; and the median is a notion based on assigning a particular order to the elements of a set.